# What does an employer look for in a CV?

Tags: software-industry, resume, career-development, student

I am a senior computer science student. I will graduate this summer, but my knowledge and projects are little. I am also a good programmer, but I didn't take any certificates or interns or anything to fill my CV with. So I was thinking to make myself fail this year, and start senior year again just to take interns and have more experience in my field and take more courses. So my question is does the employer care if I fail a year? And do you think I should do this or not?

Comment: This is entirely unanswerable I'm afraid.  Every employer has different criteria for what they will or will not like to see in a candidate.

Comment: I was a psychology major with 0 CS classes, no programming experience, but I have had multiple articles published and I have been promoted half a dozen times in a programming capacity. Your degree and college creds are only useful in an extremely limited scope.  Graduate, get out there, and start getting some real world experience and you will be fine.

Comment: Keep in mind that computer scientist are in relatively high demand, so in most locations it should not be too hard to find a job. This answer might be different if your career would be in a different field (e.g. culture, social studies, ...) where it is more important to do internships and much harder to find a job.

Comment: Taking an internship after graduation would  be much saner than failing a year (and it signals to companies that you are in it for the experience and not out of necessity).

Comment: A lot of people are in the same situation when they just graduated. Yes, there are employers who look for the impossible "five years of industry experience, but takes a salary for a new graduate", but that is honestly their problem, not yours. Be reasonable with what kind of first job you would like and they should be reasonable with their expectations. You will get experience enough later on.

Comment: For a fresh graduate with no job experience - we're pretty much just looking to see if you can write a coherent sentence, your course synopsis, and of you did a "cool" project in your degree.

Answer (score 9):

Making yourself fail to earn more experience is a bad decision. There are many graduate with no extra certificates or intensive work experience just like you.

Instead, I would recommend you to build a portfolio for yourself. Start developing some POC application with your desired programming language and place them in communities like github and make a reference to them in your CV. Create something that worth mentioning and displaying during your job interview.

If you have no idea what to implement, or don't know where to start. Try reading books that teaches programming by implementing one application phase by phase. (there are plenty of books like this)

Comment: POC - Proof of Concept

Answer (score 5):

Do not fail a year! That will not be good for your GPA and while some employers don't much care about it, it can be important to getting your first job after university. Employers notice if it takes someone n+1 years to finish an n-year program and it doesn't look good on a resume.

Having internships on your resume is important, but I don't think getting just a couple (I'm not sure how many you can do in your final year) is worth the hit to your GPA and making employers wonder why you needed an extra year to finish your degree.

I think it would be better for you in the long run to graduate on time, potentially take a job that isn't exactly your dream job, and improve your resume by building your own projects and/or contributing to open source in your free time.